# Clicking PUBLISH Now Redirects to 404 PAGE NOT FOUND

Tags: htaccess, 404-error

I have a Wordpress blog running Sahifa Theme. I am unable to post anything on my blog . When ever I goto the NEW POST Page , I create a title , add content to post and post it. it works fine unless the post content , contains any PHP or Python code. My website mostly includes PHP Code examples, So when I add that PHP code block , it doesn't post it, instead redirects me to a 404 NOT FOUND page. This happens only when I add code in it.
[HERE IS A VIDEO CAST OF THE ERROR](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6RusiCmGTsjU25Kc1M4VkxTdkE/view)

Comment: one thing to check is with your hosting provider whether they have (or you have?) a security measure in place that is blocking the posting of code, if so they may need to loosen the restrictions for your account.

Comment: @majick No, They have no such restrictions . I already have couple of posts on the same site with code blocks and stuff

Comment: it is hard to know for sure what code can trigger a security rule, I only mentioned it as a possibility because it happened to me recently... do you have a security plugin active? that could be doing a similar thing.

Comment: @majick
No, I have no security plugin. And this problem was taking place for the last 8-9 months. yesterday I made a fresh install and restored my posts and images from a backup . Do you need access to my website to see if you can help me with this ?

Comment: I suggest you dig into your server error logs to see if there is anything relevant to a 404 at the time of publishing content, and post this to your question so others can help you also.

Comment: @majick Already did that , There are no error logs of that time :(

Comment: hmmm well I guess you could try turning on WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php and seeing if that provides you with any errors for the time in /wp-content/debug.log ... also worth checking for any PHP error logs in /wp-admin/ ... otherwise you'd probably need a more hefty debug plugin/tool to narrow this down.